# ¿Como se puede pasar parámetros del reporte principal al subreport, en ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Quisera mostrar una tabla maestro-detalle usando subreport. Por ejemplo, tengo la tabla región(tabla padre) y la tabla(ciudad). Quisiera mostrar todas las regiones del país, pero por cada región, mostrar en detalle las ciudades que la contiene.

La idea mía es pasar el parámetro que es el id de la región al subreporte de la ciudad, ya que este debería mostrar dependiendo de la región.

Comment: cuando agregas un subreporte, en las propiedades hay una seccion de parametro, en esta podes indicar una exprecion

Comment: mmm..ok, pero hay una opcion que dice name y value. Mi duda es el name, que nombre debería colocarle?.

Comment: el nombre del parametro en el subreporte, ejemplo si en la consulta del reporte se llama ID_Casa, tenes que ponerle igual en ese campo

Comment: en este link podes encontrar mas informacion https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348(v=sql.100).aspx